# Сумма значений столбца в связанных таблицах sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Как нужно написать sql запрос, чтобы посчитать Сумму столбца Количество для Города Мытищи (на рисунке две связанные таблицы)?

[image]

Предполагаю, что запрос должен быть что-то типа этого `Select SUM(Количество) FROM Таблица_верхняя, Таблица_нижняя WHERE Город='Мытищи' And Таблица_нижняя.КодМагазина = Таблица_верхняя.КодМагазина`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Sum(`Таблица_верхняя`.`Количество`) 
FROM `Таблица_верхняя` 
INNER JOIN `Таблица_нижняя` 
ON (`Таблица_верхняя`.`КодМагазина` = `Таблица_нижняя`.`КодМагазина` )
WHERE `Таблица_нижняя`.`Город` LIKE 'Мытищи'
```